# How to set and save a default variable javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple template engine.
I came up with this

//test data

```
data = {
    "car": "BMW",
    "year": "2015"
}
```

//prepare the default template by cloning the first load

```
elem = window.document.getElementById("mytemplate");
function prepare(templ) {
    var template = elem.cloneNode(true);
    return template;
}
```

//get default template and append data into then append result after selected node

```
function append(templ) {
    text = templ.innerHTML;
    match = text.match(/\{{.*?}\}/g);
    console.log(match);
    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        text = text.replace(match[i], data[match[i].replace(/\W+/g, "")]);
        templ.innerHTML = text;
        elem.parentNode.appendChild(templ.cloneNode(true));
    }
}
```

//regular renderer will render data to the default node

```
function render(templ) {
    var text = templ.innerHTML;
    var match = text.match(/\{{.*?}\}/g);
    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        var text = text.replace(match[i], data[match[i].replace(/\W+/g, "")]);
        elem.innerHTML = text;
    }
}


render(prepare(elem ));
append(prepare(elem ));
append(prepare(elem ));
```

//HTML

```
<p id="mytemplate">{{car}} - {{year}}</p>
```

My problem is when I use the render function. I will no longer be able to use the append function because the default template is gone when I have saved it into the "elem" var. Now my question is how to save such a variable and be able to use it multiple times?

Comment: Do you look at your code with no indentation or spacing of any kind? If the answer is no, please don't ask us to and format it for readability. If the answer is yes, please don't ask us to and format it for readability.

Comment: I really couldn't find a way of explaining this other than posting this large code and I thought it is readable.
my main question is my question title.

Comment: simplest solution - wait for es2015 :p - but in the meantime, format your code using http://jsbeautifier.org/